# Goto was unexpected at this time please

Tags: batch-file

im messing around for a secret file that i can type in and just keep things to myself here is the code

```
@echo off
echo PLEASE ENTER THE PASSWORD TO CONTINUE
set /p password="hello"
IF %c%==hello goto top
IF NOT %c%==goto PASSERROR
:passsuccess
title matrix
color 0a
mode 1000
:top
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
goto top
:passerror
echo try again
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Don't you mean " ELSE goto PASSERROR" on the 5th line? btw read the guides on asking a question.

Comment: it keeps saying goto was unexpected at this time

Comment: Does it give you a line number? Is this your entire code because it doesn't look complete.

Comment: no it just says goto was unexpected at this time and no it is not complete

Comment: IF NOT %c%==goto PASSERROR looks fishy to me. Try commenting it out. Its possible you have lots of places that gotos aren't supposed to be so it is hard to tell without all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `c` is undefined. You are entering the password into `password` then checking `c`.

In case of spaces or no entry, use

```
if "%varentered%"=="somevalue" goto ...
```

For instance,

```
if "%c%"=="" goto paserror
```

or

```
if not defined c goto ...
```

as you have it, if `%c%` is not equal to `goto`, execute the executable `passerror`

Comment: I would add that he needs `IF NOT "%c%"=="hello" goto PASSERROR` instead of `IF NOT %c%==goto PASSERROR`